# Need help creating a function that loops over list of csv files, selects certain columns and saves them as csv's again

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've created a list using the below code:

```
path = r'M:\BI\HisRms'

fileList = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            fileList.append(file)
```

print of file list for context:

```
['736815-RM.csv', '736816-RM.csv', '736817-RM.csv', '736818-RM.csv', '736819-RM.csv', '736820-RM.csv', '736821-RM.csv', '736822-RM.csv', '736823-RM.csv', '736824-RM.csv', '736825-RM.csv', '736826-RM.csv', '736827-RM.csv', '736828-RM.csv', '736829-RM.csv', '736830-RM.csv', '736831-RM.csv', '736832-RM.csv', '736833-RM.csv', '736834-RM.csv', '736835-RM.csv', '736836-RM.csv', '736837-RM.csv', '736838-RM.csv', '736839-RM.csv', '736840-RM.csv', '736841-RM.csv', '736842-RM.csv', '736843-RM.csv', '736844-RM.csv', '736845-RM.csv', '736846-RM.csv', '736847-RM.csv', '736848-RM.csv', '736849-RM.csv', '736850-RM.csv']
```

Now that i have the list i need to be able to define a function that does the below:

"For each file in my file list, select A,B,C,D columns and remove all other columns. Then save it down using the same name of the file but to a different folder"

I've been able to do this for each individual file (stupidly manual) using the below code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('736818-RM.csv', index_col= 0, encoding = 'iso-8859-1')

df2 = df[['Purchase Order','SKU','Markdown','Landed Cost','Original Price','Current Sale Price','Free Stock','OPO','ID Style','Supplier Style No']]

df2.to_csv(r"C:\Users\jonathon.kindred\Desktop\RM\2019\FEB 2019\736818-RM", index = False)
```

but i have over 500 + files that i need to amend and i don't really have the time to do this by file.

Any help, or points in the right direction would be great!

Comment: you kind of did everything, I don't really see what's lacking... just a for loop?

Comment: @Gulzar yeah, i can't build the for loop. I can't wrap my head around it, need someone to show me so i can understand

Comment: Same fields in all files?

Comment: @Gulzar yes, the same fields in all of the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
path = r'M:\BI\HisRms'

fileList = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            fileList.append(file)

for name in fileList:
    df = pd.read_csv(name, index_col= 0, encoding = 'iso-8859-1')

    df2 = df[['Purchase Order','SKU','Markdown','Landed Cost','Original Price','Current Sale Price','Free Stock','OPO','ID Style','Supplier Style No']]

    df2.to_csv(os.path.join("C:/", "Users", "jonathon.kindred", "Desktop", "RM", "2019", "FEB 2019", name), index = False)
```